# How change chart height in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I would create an horizontal bar chart.

The problem is that I can't change the height of the chart ( not the bar )

I created my data and options configuration:

```
  this.data = {
        labels: ['SAF/TGA'],
        datasets: [

            {
                label: 'SAF/TGA',
                backgroundColor: '#9CBB65',
                borderColor: '#72242',
                data: [28],

            }
        ],
  }
  this.options= {
            responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false

        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          barThickness: 5,
          gridLines:{
          display: true,
          offsetGridLines: false
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines:"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
        }]
      },

    }
}
```

then I call my chart in HTML with height and width options:

```
<p-chart type="horizontalBar" [data]="data" [options]="options" width="10" height="10px">
</p-chart>
```

[image: actual behaviour]
The height does not change when I change the values `height` in html

And this is what I would

[image: expected behaviour]

With the axes that gets closer to the bar.

Answer (score 10):

Try changing the options to disable the aspect ratio

```
var chart = new Chart('bar_charty', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {},
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  }
});
```

This should scale your chart when you make the height on the containing element larger.

You might also need to create a container for the chart like this, and set it's height in the parent.

```
<div style="height: 300px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes issues in IE11